# Symbol lookup error: libgeometry_shape.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6Assimp8Importer18SetPropertyIntegerEPKciPb

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

System Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo (updated to the latest already)

This problem confuses me for days. So every time I start the move_group or the rviz this error occurs, I then checked the library in the /opt/ros/indigo/lib and dumped the strings in file libgeometry_shapes.so and found that the undefined symbol is actually in there.

I have another Ubuntu 14.04 with Indigo and the move_group is working fine, I am not quite sure why it's not happy with the libgeometry_shapes.so, the only thing I have done to this Ubuntu is that I used the nvidia-375 driver for the graphic card in order to use cuda for the KinectV2, can this possibly be the cause?

Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266321/symbol-lookup-error:-libgeometry_shape.so:-undefined-symbol:-_zn6assimp8importer18setpropertyintegerepkcipb/) by [boooooosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31171/boooooosh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not exactly an answer, but I figured out why. ROS moveit uses a dynamic library called assimp, but only works with assimp v3.0, not assimpv3.2, that is where goes wrong, I think.
Anybody facing the same problem or do anyone how to manually link to another library?

---

Originally posted by [boooooosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31171/boooooosh/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-07-17**:
Why did you install assimpv3.2 on ubuntu 14.04?
Most likely they broke ABI. So you have to recompile libraries
in `/opt/ros/` that use assimp to use the new version.
Otherwise problems are to be expected.

**Comment by [boooooosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31171/boooooosh/) on 2017-07-17**:
That's true, I cover the assimp 3.2 with assimp 3.0 and the problem is fixed. The reason why I have a assimp 3.2 is probably because I installed cuda or changed to Nvidia graphic card and the library is automatically installed.